# Best way to take a UIGestureRecognizer event and get the root container view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController where I'm adding bunch of UIViews as subviews. Then I attach UIGestureRecognizer to each, so I can be notified when there's a tap. Here's the code inside the UIViewController:

```
- (void)attachSubview{
  UIImageView *childView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"child"]] ;
  UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
  [childView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
  [self.view addSubView childView];
}

- (void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
  NSLog(@"Tapped view : %@", recognizer.view);
  NSLog(@"The root view is : %@", self.view);
}
```

Now, here's the problem: I actually want to extract these two methods out into a separate class. In this case I can't use the `self.view` inside the `tapped:` method, since self wouldn't be the viewcontroller class anymore.

So I would like a simple and efficient way to just take the recognizer object and somehow get the root view to which the image view belongs. What is the best and future proof way to do this?

Comment: You can make custom subview and use delegates,

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this please?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   //example of its use. You can replace with [className attachSubview:self.view] for example
   self.view = [self attachSubview:self.view];
}

- (UIView *)attachSubview:(UIView *)passedInView{
   UIImageView *childView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"child"]] ;
   UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
   [childView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
   [passedInView addSubview:passedInView];
   return passedInView;
}

- (void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
   NSLog(@"Tapped view : %@", recognizer.view);
   NSLog(@"The root view is : %@", recognizer.view.superview);
}
```

Comment: If this helped solve your problem can you mark it as accepted please. If not let me know and I'll see if I can help further